# Passing a const reference of a NavigationPane results in error

Tags: c++, qt, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

Using BlackBerry 10 Cascades, I create a class:

```
MyClass : public QObject
{
 QObject
  public:
    MyClass(const bb::cascades::NavigationPane & navigationPane);
    //...
  protected:
    bb::cascades::NavigationPane m_navigationPane;
```

In the ccp file I have this in the constructor:

```
MyClass::MyClass(const bb::cascades::NavigationPane & navigationPane)
{
    m_navigationPane = navigationPane;
```

When I build, it gives me the error:

`'bb::cascades::NavigationPane& bb::cascades::NavigationPane::operator=(const bb::cascades::NavigationPane&)' is private`

Comment: It's pretty self explanatory, the = operator is private for a NavigationPane, you can't use it

Comment: How would I pass a reference to an existing navigation pane in a constructor of a class?

Comment: Use an initializer list, If that doesn't work you'll have to pass it without copying, using a reference type

Comment: I normally use a pointer to pass nav panes, but after reading further, I think with a & is better.  Maybe I don't understand the proper way to do it in c++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing that class, it is clear that it can't be copied. The error message is quite clear: its copy assignment operator is private. This is usually done on purpose to avoid copying.

From its name I guess that it represents a real resource; it makes no sense copying the object, because the resource is unique.

I understand that what you need is really the object you are getting in the constructor. Assuming that it will last as long as the `MyClass` instance you are creating with it, you can use a reference member in your class. This can only be initialised in the initialisation list of the constructor, this way:

```
MyClass : public QObject
{
 QObject
  public:
    MyClass(const bb::cascades::NavigationPane & navigationPane);
    //...
  protected:
    const bb::cascades::NavigationPane& m_navigationPane;
```

And then the constructor will be:

```
MyClass::MyClass(const bb::cascades::NavigationPane & navigationPane)
: m_navigationPane(navigationPane)
{
//    m_navigationPane = navigationPane;
```

Of course, if you need to actually modify the `NavigationPane` instance from inside your `MyClass` object, you just have to use non-const references and everything will work fine.

Comment: that's what I was trying to do.  Thank you so much.